# JQuery plugin, Javascript - How create only  for JQuery plugin global variable, or json object and change this (variable, object) in function level

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, global-variables

I use JQuery : 1.6.4

My target it's create function who, without giving varabiles in (), can start and stop Script.

When i tried reach.. target.. I was found a few problems...

1. Specyfic variable\s only for JQuery plugin, with acces from funcions (change variables)
2. functions move_text

Result for div 190px , and distance 2.5px

190, 187.5, 190... We can.. se fault change of global variable

Should be 190, 187.5, 185...

How resolve this problem (JSON ? Window)?

I tried way with JSON, object... but... i waste a lot of time.. And nothing find...

So.. Way with window['distance_iv'] is Good?

Here is my code :

```
$.fn.emulate_marquee = function( options ) {

    var settings = {
      'ob_name': '', // object who we use...
      'direction': 'left', 
      'scroll_amount': 100, 
      'delay': 25 // Animation speed
    };

    //call in the default otions
            options = $.extend(settings, options);

            return this.each(function(options) {



                var object = $(settings.ob_name);
                window['distance_ob'] = width = object.width(); 

                //object.css(settings.direction , width + 'px'); // Set Width
                //alert(width);

                total_width  = (2 * width) / settings.scroll_amount;
                // total_width

                settings.distance = settings.scroll_amount / (1000/ settings.delay); // Calculate distance for one frame

                width_s = screen.width; // Get screen width




               next_obj = setTimeout (function(){ 
                            move_text()
                          }, 1);

               /*next_res = setTimeout (function(){ 
                            resolution_ch()
                          }, 1);

                */

                var move_text = function()
                {
                    //alert((settings.width - (i * settings.scroll_amount)) + 'px');

                    alert(window['distance_ob'] + 'px');
                    window['distance_ob'] -= settings.distance;
                    object.css(settings.direction , window['distance_ob'] + 'px');
                    alert(window['distance_ob'] + 'px');


                    if (window['distance_ob'] < total_width)
                    {
                        next_obj = setTimeout (function(){ 
                            move_text()
                        }, settings.delay); 
                    }
                    else
                    {
                       next_obj = setTimeout (function(){ 
                            move_text()
                        }, settings.delay);
                        window['distance_ob'] = width;
                    }

                }

                var resolution_ch = function()
                {
                    if (screen.width != width_s)
                    {
                        // change varabiales... for new resolution

                        width_s =  screen.width;
                        distance_ob = width = object.width();
                        alert(width_s + ' ' + object.width());
                        total_width  = (2 * width) / settings.scroll_amoun;


                        alert("Detected Change resolution.... nuke in 5 second... started...");

                    }

                    next_res = setTimeout (function(){ 
                                resolution_ch()
                               }, 1000);



                }


            });
  };
```

Comment: In firefox 7... Fault 190, 192.5, 190 (Left: (distance_ob)), function move_text ... hmm, so it's a good question

Comment: /* small update comment */
In firefox 7 and other browsers... Fault 190, 192.5, 190, ... (like a 1, 2, 1, 2) (Left: (distance_ob)), function move_text ... hmm, so I try find a good way to resolve it

Comment: Move functions should work for 190px div 190, 187.5, 185...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe try saving your global variable to `jQuery.data()` ([ref](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.data/))

But since it sounds like you might need to access methods from outside of the plugin, I would suggest checking out some different plugin patterns.

Check out this awesome "library" of [jQuery plugin patterns](https://github.com/addyosmani/jquery-plugin-patterns).

Especially look at the patterns that save the plugin instance into the jQuery data; which is done by default in all of the widget factory templates. But my personal favorite is the "jquery.namespace.plugin-boilerplate.js"

Comment: Thank you, it's working. :) But i found funny (bug) in my script with: 

total_width  = (2 * width) / settings.scroll_amount;

And this bug make

window['distance_ob'] > total_width

option 2 in if and... recursion. 

Solution is change 'total_width  = (2 * width) / settings.scroll_amount;' this to 'width' and more sleep.